# I can't push my Cocoapods library, i have a problem with the trunk push command

Tags: cocoapods, dependency-management

When I try the following command: `pod trunk push CustomUIKitItems.podspec`

The terminal gives me the following result:

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`
Validating podspec
 -> CustomUIKitItems (1.0.0)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Metadata extraction skipped. No AppIntents.framework dependency found. (in target 'CustomUIKitItems' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Metadata extraction skipped. No AppIntents.framework dependency found. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

[!] Source code for your Pod was not accessible to CocoaPods Trunk. Is it a private repo or behind a username/password on http?

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `CustomUIKitItems (1.0.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `CustomUIKitItems (1.0.0)`
```

But the repository is public, I don't understand anything!

You can have a look at the complete repository from the following link, to have a look at the .podspec or anything else

[CustomUIKitItems github repository](https://github.com/Gonzalo-MR8/CustomUIKitItems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository is missing a 1.0.0 tag. https://github.com/Gonzalo-MR8/CustomUIKitItems/tags

Comment: I didn't know I needed that, it's working now!! Thank you so much!